# Get the average of all combinations of a certain size in a column

Tags: r, combinatorics

I have a data frame with the following values:

```
data= structure(list(rating = c(5L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have 20 different options of choosing 3 values from the rating column (3 choose 6). I would like to create a vector that will give me the averages of all the possible combinations (20 averages in total).

I could not figure out a way to do this with R. It would be great if you have an idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` to get the combinations of selecting 3 values and use `colMeans` on the resulting `matrix`

```
colMeans(combn(data$rating, 3))
#[1] 4.333333 4.000000 2.666667 2.666667 6.000000 4.666667 4.666667 4.333333 4.333333 3.000000 4.666667 3.333333 3.333333 3.000000 3.000000
#[16] 1.666667 5.000000 5.000000 3.666667 3.333333
```

---

Or make use of the `FUN`

```
combn(data$rating, 3, FUN = mean)
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks.